# unpacking viewdata in foreach statement

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

So I packed some query results in a viewdata statement.

I can verify the correct number of results are put into the viewdata object in the view with this directive:

```
@foreach (var action in (List<LemonadeTrader.Models.Message>)ViewData["messages"]) {
```

When I try to display the results:

```
@Html.DisplayFor( (LemonTrader.Models.Message)action.msg)   // action.msg should be of type string
```

It says it couldn't convert string to LemonTrader.Models.Lemon.

When I cast it as:

```
@Html.DisplayFor( (string)action.acidity)
```

It says:

> The type arguments for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor(System.Web.Mvc.‌
>   ​HtmlHelper,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try
>   specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

Not casting it at all doesn't work either.

How do I cast the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
@foreach (var action in (List<LemonTrader.Models.Message>)ViewData["lemons"]) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.Encode( action.acidity)
```

Answer (score 1):

`DisplayFor/EditorFor` works with strongly typed views and view models. It takes as first argument a lambda expression which represents the property on your view model you are trying to display/edit. So throw this `ViewData` into the dustbin (which is where it belongs) and use view models and strongly typed views.

So instead of the following horror:

```
@foreach (var action in (List<LemonadeTrader.Models.Message>)ViewData["messages"]) {
```

You will have a view model with a Messages property of the correct type:

```
@foreach (var action in Model.Messages) {
```

Or even better (why writing `foreach` loops when dislpay/editor templates already do this):

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Messages)
```

This way you get many bonuses:

- your code will work
- you get intellisense
- no more brittle magic strings
- instead of resembling to some spaghetti code your views become far more readable
- ...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I couldn't find any good model examples where multiple models are returned to a view. It looked like you can only return one to a view. Your explanation here helped explain the motivation for using strongly-typed models, which I hadn't seen before. Thanks!

Comment: @micahhoover, it's true that you can return only a single model to a view. So you define a view model which could contain properties of other types, this way you could pass whatever models you like to the view.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just a syntax error, because the DisplayFor expects a Func that gets your model as input.
Try this: `@Html.DisplayFor(m => (string)action.acidity)`

Comment: I got this error: "Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions."